# Prime NG multi select init value cannot see check box selected

Tags: primeng, primeng-dropdowns

Prime NG multi select init value cannot see check box selected

init method

```
  this.cities =  [
  {label: 'New York', value: 'NY'},
  {label: 'Rome', value: 'RM'},
  {label: 'London', value: 'LDN'},
  {label: 'Istanbul', value: 'IST'},
  {label: 'Paris', value: 'PRS'}];
```

let selectedT: Country[];

selectedT = [{label: "Rome", value: "RM"}];

this.dForm.controls["selectedCities"].setValue([{label: "Rome", value: "RM"}]);

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass the whole object to "selectedCities" Array. Pass the only value to an array.

```
selectedT = ["RM"];

this.dForm.controls["selectedCities"].setValue(["RM"]);
```